# how to download pdf using NodeJS and send it to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express

I am trying to download a PDF file using NodeJS then send its data to client to be embedded in the page. Here is how I download the PDF file:

```
exports.sendPdf = function(req, responce) {
    var donneRecu = req.body;
    var url = 'http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf'//pdf link
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('downloading');
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", function() {
            console.log('downloaded');
            responce.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            responce.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
            responce.header(200, {'content-type' : 'application/pdf'});
            responce.send(data);
        });
    }).on("error", function() {
        callback(null);
    });
}
```

How do I send the data received from NodeJS to the client side?

**EDIT**
i found the solution :

> ```
> exports.sendPdf = function(req, res) {
>
>   var donneRecu = req.body;
>
>   console.log(donneRecu['lien']);
>
>   var url = donneRecu['lien']; //pdf link
>
>   http.get(url, function(response) {
>
>       var chunks = [];
>
>       response.on('data', function(chunk) {
>
>           console.log('downloading');
>
>           chunks.push(chunk);
>
>       });
>
>       response.on("end", function() {
>           console.log('downloaded');
>           var jsfile = new Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('base64');
>           console.log('converted to base64');
>           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
>           res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
>           res.send(jsfile);
>       });
>   }).on("error", function() {
>       callback(null);
>   }); 
> }
> ```

next in my angular controller:

> ```
> var pdf = $scope.base64ToUint8Array(data);    
> PDFJS.getDocument(pdf).then(functiongetPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
> $scope.pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;$scope.renderPage($scope.pageNum); });
> ```

Comment: the client eg the browser will ask the user to save pdf or open it in browser since you set the correct content-type. I think that your desire effect, or no?

Comment: this line don't work it give me an error "responce.header(200, {'content-type' : 'application/pdf'});" and the browzer dont tell me if i would like to download it or display it .am i doing somthing wrong ??

Comment: that line should be responce.header('content-type','application/pdf');
without using stream this will work for small file, your callback(null) in error come from where?

Comment: do you need to hide the actual url of your pdf file? if not you just need to redirect your client to your pdf url without proxy the request.

Comment: no i don't want to hide my URL . I used this operation to avoid cross browsing problems.in order to achieve this i download a pdf file using nodeJS then i transfer it data to the client side where it going to be viewed.the problem i face is if the way i am downloading the pdf file correct and after i download it how to transfer it and view it in the browse

Comment: if the user click a link/button to download, no cross domain. if download initiate from javascript then cross domain problem.
now you just need to set the content-type correctly responce.header('content-type','application/pdf');

Comment: thanks now the data is transferred to the client side.I put it in                             <object id='embedpdf' data="RECIEVED-DATA" type="application/pdf" width="40%" height="100%"> do i need to convert the recieved data or somthing

Comment: Please move the solution from the question to an answer, then accept it. Reply to your own question is encouraged on Stack Overflow when it's informative. Our goal is to build a Q/A database, not only to reply then let the questions decay.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i found the solution :

> ```
> exports.sendPdf = function(req, res) {
>
>   var donneRecu = req.body;
>
>   console.log(donneRecu['lien']);
>
>   var url = donneRecu['lien']; //pdf link
>
>   http.get(url, function(response) {
>
>       var chunks = [];
>
>       response.on('data', function(chunk) {
>
>           console.log('downloading');
>
>           chunks.push(chunk);
>
>       });
>
>       response.on("end", function() {
>           console.log('downloaded');
>           var jsfile = new Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('base64');
>           console.log('converted to base64');
>           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
>           res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
>           res.send(jsfile);
>       });
>   }).on("error", function() {
>       callback(null);
>   }); 
> }
> ```

next in my angular controller:

> ```
> var pdf = $scope.base64ToUint8Array(data);    
> PDFJS.getDocument(pdf).then(functiongetPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
> $scope.pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;$scope.renderPage($scope.pageNum); });
> ```

Answer (score 7):

I too faced the same situation and the below code helped me.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var file = fs.createReadStream('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
    var stat = fs.statSync('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=quote.pdf');
    file.pipe(res);
```

Hope it helps.