# How do I generate and download a PDF file using node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I'm building a web application in node.js and angular and I wish to generate a PDF that will be downloaded by the client. I am currently using phantomjs to download a PDF file. How woudl I achieve this with a node.js express app?

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readFile('/temp/example.pdf',function(error,data){
    if(error){
       res.json({'status':'error',msg:err});
    }else{
       res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/pdf"});
       res.write(data);
       res.end();       
    }
});
```

OR

```
res.download('/temp/example.pdf');
```

Comment: I am not getting understand this please explain in details. Where should i put this code in my application. i have a function `exports.getPDF`

Comment: Put it in the callback of `exports.getPDF()`

Comment: can you give me one example please in details I want to generate employee report in pdf file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171510/how-to-download-pdf-using-nodejs-and-send-it-to-the-client

Comment: please can you explain this code i am getting error `var pdf = $scope.base64ToUint8Array(data);    
PDFJS.getDocument(pdf).then(functiongetPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
$scope.pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;$scope.renderPage($scope.pageNum); });
`  **is PDFJS is a service?**

Comment: Hey Thank i have go through this document that you refer. But my question is **i have one html template i want generate that to PDF**

Comment: Currently i am using this but angular will not wait for response and it will print the angular tag in my html file

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to generate PDFs using NodeJS is to use the `pdf-master` package. You can generate static and dynamic PDFs using HTML with one function call.

Installation

```
npm install pdf-master
```

**Example**

**Step 1** - Add required packages and generate a PDF

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfMaster = require("pdf-master");
const app = express();

app.get("", async (req, res) => {

  var PDF = await pdfMaster.generatePdf("template.hbs");

  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.status(200).send(PDF);
});
```

`generatePdf()` syntax and parameters

```
generatePdf(
  templatePath, //<string>
  data, //<object>   Pass data to template(optional)
  options //<object>   PDF format options(optional)
);
```

`Step 2` - Create your HTML Template (save the template with .hbs extension instead of .html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Render dynamic data in template and PDF format options**

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfMaster = require("pdf-master");

const app = express();

app.get("", async (req, res) => {

  var students = {
      {
          id: 1,
          name: "Sam",
          age: 21
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jhon",
          age: 20
      },
      {
          id: 3,
          name: "Jim",
          age: 24
      }
  }

  let options = {
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    format: "A4",
    headerTemplate: `<h3> Header </h3>`,
    footerTemplate: `<h3> Copyright 2023 </h3>`,
    margin: { top: "80px", bottom: "100px" },
  };

  let PDF = await pdfMaster.generatePdf("template.hbs", students, options);
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.status(200).send(PDF);
});
```

**template for the above example (save the template with .hbs extension)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Student List</h1>
    <ul>
      {{#each students}}
      <li>Name: {{this.name}}</li>
      <li>Age: {{this.age}}</li>
      <br />
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

To learn more about pdf-master [visit](https://github.com/chaitanyamogal/pdf-master)